# Laravel 10 decrypted data shown with s:K:"string of length K"

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

I am upgrading a Laravel 5.2 site to 10.20.

I followed the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#encrypted-casting) to encrypt/decryt the data the Laravel 10.x way as it was done differently on 5.2 (see it used the trait Encryptable).

When retrieving encrypted data from the same database (with the same APP_KEY) in Laravel 5.2 I get `Hello World` whereas on 10.20 I get `s:11:"Hello World"`.

The other attributes that are not encrypted are shown correctly.

I searched the web for that but did not found anything pertaining to that issue. ChatGPT told me it was linked to serialization but even with that keyword I did not find the problem described somewhere.

In my model the attributes to be encrypted are cast like this :

```
        protected $casts = [
        'my_not_encrypted_attribute' => 'boolean',
        'my_encrypted_attribute_string' => 'encrypted'        
    ];
```

Can you tell me how to get rid of that prefix and only get the actual payload as in L5.2 ?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT :**
Manually defining the [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in my model requires the use of `unserialize()` to get clean data :

```
    protected function myEncryptedAttributeString(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn (string $value) => unserialize(Crypt::decryptString($value)),
        );
    }
```

So it would mean that the data stored in the database were serialized before being stored.That's weird because the Encryptable trait shows no trace of  `serialize` in the setters :

```
public function setAttribute($key, $value) {
        if (in_array($key, MyModel::getEncryptableAttributes())) {
            $value = Crypt::encrypt($value);
        }

        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
```

Nor can I find trace of `unserialize` in the getters (although for the same database the output was clean) :

```
public function getAttribute($key) {
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);
        //[...]
        $decrypted = Crypt::decrypt($value);
        //[...]
        return $decrypted;
}
```

Comment: For once, ChatGPT is correct that the `s:11:` prefix is due to serialization: https://3v4l.org/vUaGB. I've never used the `encrypted` casts attribute, so I'm not sure why it would need to serialize the encrypted value at all, but you can do this manually if you need to: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/encryption#using-the-encrypter.

Comment: I assume you have gone through the upgrade documents that are part of every major release to look for changes needed to your code?

Comment: @TimLewis Chat was actually very useful to describe the problem otherwise it is hard to search on Google. Miken32 I did not upgrade from 5.2 to 5.3 then to 5.4 ... 6.0 ... 8 ... 9 ... 10 but I started over a new 10.x project and manually copied the classes and rearrange in the 10.x way.

Comment: ChatGPT (and other LLMs) _can_ be useful, but I've also seen them spew a bunch of nonsense that _looks_ correct, but is objectively incorrect... The one time I saw it actually make up functions and try to pass them off as core PHP functions... Like any tool, be careful with it's usage, and scrutinize whatever it tells you to do.

Comment: @TimLewis I searched my old 5.2 code and could not find any occurence of serialize/unserialize. I tried in L10.20 what you suggested with manually defining accessor and the data was also delivered serialized. Could Laravel 10.20 automatically serialize decrypted data and if so how can I prevent that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5.2, the data is serialized before encryption and is unserialized before decryption.

In Laravel 10x, this is the same, except the serialization/unserialization can be skipped using a second boolean parameter.

Your issue is that you're using the `decryptString()` function, which does not automatically unserialize the data. The `decryptString()` function is just a helper function that calls `decrypt()` with the second parameter set to `false`, which turns of unserialization.

[`decryptString`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v10.21.0/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L181C1-L185):

```
public function decryptString($payload)
{
    return $this->decrypt($payload, false);
}
```

[`decrypt`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v10.21.0/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L149C1-L171):

```
public function decrypt($payload, $unserialize = true)
{
    // snip...

    return $unserialize ? unserialize($decrypted) : $decrypted;
}
```

If you change your code to use `decrypt()` instead of `decryptString()`, it should work fine for you, and you won't need to manually unserialize your data.

---

NB: There is also an `encryptString()` function, that is the complement of `decryptString()`. Again, it is a helper that just calls `encrypt()` with the second parameter set to `false` to turn off serialization.

You should make sure you are not using the `encryptString()` function, and only use the `encrypt()` funtion. If you use the `encryptString()` function in your code to start encrypting data, you're going to end up with mixed encrypted data in your database. All of the encrypted data that came from your Laravel 5.2 will be serialized, but any encrypted data that comes from `encryptString()` will not. If your encrypted data gets mixed, you won't have a consistent way to decrypt it.

Comment: Thanks @patricus you nailed it and your explanation is quite clear. Instead of defining each and every accessor / mutator, is there a way to use the `$casts=['myAttribute'=> 'encrypted',]` way and it returns the content via `decrypt` (so that it's already unserialized) ? I was thinking of overriding a Model class method in my model and use `decrypt` in place `decryptString` ?

Comment: @HelloWorld Unfortunately, the default `encrypted` casts call `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` with `false` as the second parameter. You will either need to use your own custom casts, or you can write a one-time script to go through the encrytped data in your database, decrypt it using `decrypt()`, and then re-encrypt it using `encrypt()` with `false` as the second parameter. This will get all your encrypted data formatted in the way the Laravel cast is expecting.

Comment: Thanks again @patricus. Custom casts seem to be a clean way of achieving my goal! I have to dig into this!